# how to get full name in these table in query from these tables

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have these tables

**person**  table with following columns

person_id

description

---

**person_name** table with following columns

person_id

first_name

---

**father** table with following columns

person_father_id

description

---

**childern** table with following columns

person_father_id

person_child_id

---

how to get full name of person whereas each person has his own first name only.

Comment: Where do you have problems and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I cant get full name from this relational tables in one select  query

Comment: "Full name" is ... what? First name + last name? And all you have is *first name*? Unless you know that very person (so you know his/her last name), or know their phone number (so that you could call them and ask for their last name), huh ... no idea.

Comment: all names until no body related to the person . may be the one hundred names

Comment: @abusaad I think you mean `Abu`(father) or `bin`(son) for naming in Arabic culture, instead of `First name` and `Family name(surname)` in other parts of the world. And that makes the question not understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions about the foreign keys between the children and person_name tables, but if I'm correct this would do it. I'm, also assuming that the spelling of the children table name is incorrect.

```
select c.person_father_id, c.person_child_id, 
       father.first_name as parent_name, child.first_name as child_name
from children c
join person_name as father on father.person_id=person_father_id
join person_name as child on child.person_id=person_child_id
where child.first_name<>parent.first_name
```

Comment: thanks for your Responsiveness. but I need the name of person

Comment: Again with my assumptions, I've added the names. If this is not the names you are after then we will need more information about relationships between your keys.